# Error: Cannot find module 'readline-sync' : Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse

I have never used node.js before, and I have been researching the answer to this question, but I have had no luck.

I am trying to allow the user to enter an input number (and honestly have no idea how to do this). Upon some research I tested a very simple input/output code:

```
var readline = require('readline-sync');

var term1 = readline.question("Please enter your first binary term: ");

console.log("your number : " + term1);
```

But when I try this I am getting the error:

```
module.js:550
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'readline-sync'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/<name>/eclipse-workspace/319/SE319Assignment4/binaryCalc.js:1:78)
at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

I was wondering if anyone can help me figure out why readline-sync cannot be read, or if there is a better way to write this simple input/output code in general! Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you don't have the dependency listed in your package.json file, try running this command from your cmd (cd into the directory where binaryCalc.js is located at):

```
npm install --save readline-sync
```

if you do have it in there, just try

```
npm install
```

Comment: Where is this added?

Comment: should be in the same directory as the binaryCalc.js file.

Comment: if you want it to run on your machine only, you can execute from your cmd from anywhere: npm install -g readline-sync

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should create a dependency first 
So for that just open your folder where your js file is there through  terminal. And just follow the following  steps. 
. npm init
. npm  install readline-sync --save
and after  this just try to run your code
It will definately not show any error

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the 'readline-sync' dependency listed in your package.json file, you can try installing it by running the following command from your terminal or command prompt (while in the directory where your project is located):

```
npm install readline-sync
```

Or

```
npm install -D readline-sync @types/readline-sync
```

Or install it manually

```
"readline-sync": "^1.4.9"
```

then run the following command

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that, just uninstall code runner extension, it is the barrier.
Use external terminal by adding a line in `launch.json` file

```
"console": "externalTerminal"
```

Try Now.