# How to get readline-sync working in JavaScript in VisualStudioCode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, node-modules, package.json, readline-sync

I would like to allow a JavaScript program running in VisualStudioCode to use readline-sync, but when I try to use the
const input = require('readline-sync');
line that works in environments like Replit after causing that module to be added, I get an error message about not having the appropriate module. In trying to find an answer to this question, I have gotten the impression that modifying a "package.json" file is involved. However, I'm not sure exactly where this file is supposed to be and believe that I may not have one for my current project yet. When I use VSC's Command Palette to enter the
JavaScript: Go to Project Configuration
command, I get a popup in the lower-right corner that says
"Please open a folder in VS Code to use a TypeScript or JavaScript project
Source: TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features (Extension)"

I believe that the problem may have something to do with the fact that I have previously mainly used VSC for standalone code pages that interacted only with the console or with languages other than JavaScript and am not really familiar with how to set up a project that requires multiple files to work in conjunction in the VSC environment.

Comment: see: [Error: Cannot find module 'readline-sync' : Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52675705/error-cannot-find-module-readline-sync-node-js/52675740)